# Memory spike in redis on connecting clients

Tags: redis, connection

So I tried simple opening a 5k connections to redis and I am not performing any operation.

I still see around used_memory around 100mb  being used and used_memory_peak is around 180 mb. What is consuming this memory?

Here how my "CLIENT LIST" looks for all the connections

id=11639 addr=10.55.198.141:57044 fd=1622 name= age=16 idle=16 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=auth

Answer (score 1):

There is always over head with keeping a connection open. See the Redis source at:

https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/networking.c#L64

With 5000 connections it would be hard to not affect memory as the server has to handle and store the connection so it can reply.